# Why ubuntu SDK do not Highlight HTM code?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, html5

I just sterted with the ubuntu SDK, but, hell, the Highlight not even works!

How can I make the Highlight to work like it should do, in the settings, the mimetype handler use a simple text file style for the HTML code.

Every programer needs the highlight working is a great help for us.

Please tellme that there is a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're asking about syntax highlighting in Qt Creator, the IDE associated with the Ubuntu SDK.  If not, you'll need to clarify what you're talking about.

In Qt Creator, select Tools > Options > Text Editor > Generic Highlighter.  Ensure the check box next to "Use fallback location" is checked.  Also, ensure that there is a path in the text box below this.  On my system, this path is `/usr/share/qtcreator/generic-highlighter`.

While Qt Creator is excellent with QML and C++ files, I find it rather poor for HTML files.  I tend to use my text editor of choice to actually edit HTML files for my HTML5 project, and only open Qt Creator to run the project on an emulator.